# How to redirect to unauthenticated user using express-jwt

Tags: node.js, express, express-jwt

This is my first express app. I am trying to implement authentication for some of the routes. Ideally, if users are not authenticated, they will be redirected to the home page. So I wrote this middleware:

```
var jwt = require('express-jwt');

app.get('/protected',
  jwt({secret: 'shhhhhhared-secret'}),      //express-jwt middleware
  function(req, res, next) {                //redirection middleware
    if(!req.user._id){
      console.log('authentication failed')
      res.redirect('/home')
    }else{
      next()
    };
  });
```

If the user is logged in, the code works. However, if user is not logged in, the browser simply show a 401 unauthorized error. There is no redirection. The process failed at the express-jwt middleware and did not continue to my redirection middleware.

Is there some configuration which i need to set within the jwt function? Or do is there a way to set a global redirection if 401 is encountered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If user is not authenticated error is thrown and node.js stops code execution. After that you would be able to catch it in express error handler:

```
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    if(401 == err.status) {
        res.redirect('/home')
    }
  });
```

Comment: Is this code supposed to place before the authentication middleware or after?

Comment: This middleware should be the last one. Don't forget to handle other errors in if else. You could send sms or email with error description or just save them in database.